# Is it possible Windows 10 upgrade uninstalled antivirus software?

Tags: installation, security, windows-10, anti-virus, uninstall

Was using Trend Micro Titanium.  Upgraded from windows 7.  Used to see a notification saying Trend Micro was scanning in Windows 7.  I haven't seen the notification in a month.  Found the installation folder under c:\program files (64-bit).  All the files were present.  Could not find Trend Micro installed under "add/remove programs."  Could not find it in Windows 10's list of apps.

Is it possible the upgrade was the cause for the uninstallation?  Is it possible the software is not compatible and it simply uninstalled itself?  Did malware uninstall it?

Comment: You're better off without it.

Comment: Did your version specifically support Windows 10?

Answer (score 2):

This is what it says in the Windows 10 specification

> For anti-malware applications, Windows will check to see if your anti-malware subscription is current (not expired) and compatible during the upgrade.
>   If the anti-malware application is compatible and current, your application will be preserved during the upgrade to Windows 10.
>   If the anti-malware application is incompatible, Windows will uninstall your application while preserving your settings. After upgrade is complete, if your anti-malware provider has informed Microsoft that it has made a compatible version available for your active subscription, Windows will notify you to install the latest version available with the settings that were set prior to upgrade.
>   If your anti-malware subscription is not current (expired), Windows will uninstall your application and enable Windows Defender.
>   [Source](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-10-specifications)

So it's possible it was uninstalled.